# Algorithm for generating random UML instances

Tags: uml

I'm working on a tool which would make UML models less ambiguous (using EMF and UML2 frameworks for Eclipse). In order to do this I am creating instances of different parts of the model. Does anyone know any efficient algorithms for generating RANDOM model instances?

Comment: hmm, would be interesting to know how are you trying to achieve your goal...
as for the algorithm I guess it would be reasonable to use algorithm for generation of random graphs and go from there by adding some constraints on nodes and edges, try e.g. this <a href="http://www.stanford.edu/~saberi/randomgraph.pdf">paper about sequential random graph generation algorithm</a>.

Comment: Hey Gabriel.Yeah, I should have given more explanations. I've been trying to evaluate OCL constraints on model instances programatically. I've been trying to do this in RSA, but it seems that the OCL evaluation on a model level is not supported. So what I do, is that I use emf ecore model in order to generate the code which would allow me to create model instances (which respect the OCL constraints written in the metamodel). Finally I would like to create objectDiagrams to represent all the generated instances. I need to put all this together and it's not very simple. What do you think?

Answer (score 1):

Do you know the [USE Tool](http://www.db.informatik.uni-bremen.de/projects/USE/#download). This tool has exactly the same purpose (it´s not integreated with EMF though): to generate instances of a UML/OCL class diagram to see if the model is too much (or too little) restrictive. There´s a kind of scripting language to define what kind of instances (and how many) do you want the tool to generate.

However, I think the most flexible way to achieve this is by translating your UML/OCL model to a CSP (constraint satisfaction problem) or similars. Then you can ask the CSP solver to generate as many instances of the model as you want and, by adding additional constraints, you can easily tune the kind of instances to be generated. Our tool [UMLtoCSP](http://gres.uoc.edu/UMLtoCSP/) could be used to automatically generate the CSP code for you (hopefully we will have soon the resources to restructure the tool and migrate it to Eclipse/EMF but at least you may get an idea of what I say with the current tool version). This idea is similar to what you can do with Alloy but with better support for numerical constraints and a more integrated translation

Answer (score 0):

hmm.  Are you trying to build some kind of simulation/verification tool?

If so have you looked at [alloy](http://alloy.mit.edu/alloy4/faq.php) and its accompanying analyzer?

From the FAQ:

What is alloy?

> Alloy is similar to OCL, the Object
>   Language of UML, but it has a more
>   conventional syntax and a simpler
>   semantics, and is designed for
>   automatic analysis.

What's the alloy analyzer?

> The Alloy Analyzer is a constraint
>   solver that provides fully automatic
>   simulation and checking.

Language / tool may or may not be relevant - but the [community](http://alloy.mit.edu/community/og) might be a good source of help.